# horiontally aligning youtube responsive youtube videos

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, youtube, flexbox

I'm trying to embed two videos (one from youtube and one from facebook), side by side, using flexbox, but I need to make them responsive.  I've browsed other questions on the site, and they've been helpful, but I'm still having an issue with the video on the left displaying 2x the height as the video on the right.  Can anyone please take a look and let me know what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="video">
  <div class="video-header">
    <h1>VIDEO</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="youtube-top">

    <div class="video-responsive1">
      <iframe width="650" height="350" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gghVoRX-sn0?rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>

    <div class="video-responsive2">
      <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fdjtrentino%2Fvideos%2F10153921589011137%2F&show_text=0&width=560" width="650" height="350" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>


.youtube-top {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.video-responsive1{
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  height: 0;
}
.video-responsive1 iframe{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.video-responsive2{
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  height: 0;
}
.video-responsive2 iframe{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.video-responsive1,
.video-responsive2{
  flex: 1;
}
```

[video image - rendering incorrectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXMm4.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's my solution on codepen.](https://codepen.io/mrcharlie/pen/ZxNPBG)

### HTML

```
<div class="video">
  <div class="video-header">
    <h1>VIDEO</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="video-container">

    <div class="video-responsive">
      <div class="aspect-ratio-16-9">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gghVoRX-sn0?rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>  
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="video-responsive">
      <div class="aspect-ratio-16-9">
        <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fdjtrentino%2Fvideos%2F10153921589011137%2F&show_text=0&width=560" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.video-responsive {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 56.25%;
  margin: 0 -1px;
}

.aspect-ratio-16-9 {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 56.25%; 
  position: relative;
}

.video-responsive iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

---

General comments:

1. You don't need flex. Flex is for when you don't know the widths of content, or you need to vertically align stuff. Using `display: block` works just fine here, with children `width: 50%`. Note the `margin: 0 -1px`, that's just a quick fix because the `display: inline-block` will create extra horizontal padding.
2. You don't need to set the width/height in the HTML. You can, and I'm sure there are recommendations for setting it; my solution doesn't have it.
3. You need an aspect ratio class. This will constrain the children to the appropriate size.
4. Learn and use BEM for class naming. Using `video-responsive1` & `2` makes the code more confusing to read and debug, and in this case, you don't even need them to be different.

Comment: Thank you!  This worked perfectly.  I'm still learning a lot of this so I truly appreciate your help.

Comment: @cubs_fan35 if it worked, please mark the question as solved :)